# CSS resizable images with header

Tags: html, css, image, resize, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to get an HTML layout of two images that are shown side-by-side, and fill the page while maintaining their aspect ratio and keeping the images next to each other (i.e. NOT in the centre of each half of the page). I also want a header at the top. I have almost achieved this using the CSS hackery below. Currently it looks like this:

[image: a]

If I shrink it horizontally the images shrink as expected (note SO has fit the images to width but the "Choose an image." text size is constant in reality).

[image: b]

The problem is that my images are filling the entire page, because I am using the CSS `vw` and `vh` units (view width and view height). They let you set a width or height to a percentage of the entire view, but not of the enclosing div so I can't just put it in a div (an `iframe` would work but ugh). Because my header is absolutely positioned, when I shrink the window vertically it looks like this:

[image: c]

My code is below. Does anyone know how to fix this without resorting to javascript resizing?

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 /* Fix CSS. */
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body
{
 margin: 20px;
}

html
{
 background-color: #f4f4f6;
}

.halfContainer
{
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

#leftContainer
{
    left: 0;
}

#rightContainer
{
    right: 0;
}

/* AR is height/width. */

#leftImage
{
    /* Set to half width, minus padding. 50-padding = 45 */
    width: 45vw; 
 /* Multiply by aspect ratio. 45 * AR = ... */
    /*height: 35vw;*/
    /* Clip by height if necessary, minus padding. 100-padding*2 = 90 */
    max-height: 90vh;
 /* Divide by aspect ratio. 90 / AR = ... */
    /*max-width: 140vh; */
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 5%; /* Padding */
}


#rightImage
{
    /* Set to half width, minus padding. 50-padding = 45 */
    width: 45vw; 
 /* Multiply by aspect ratio. 45 * AR = ... */
    /*height: 35vw;*/
    /* Clip by height if necessary, minus padding. 100-padding*2 = 90 */
    max-height: 90vh;
 /* Divide by aspect ratio. 90 / AR = ... */
    /*max-width: 140vh;*/
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 5%;
}

#instructions
{
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1 id="instructions">Choose an image.</h1></center>

<div id="leftContainer" class="halfContainer">
 <img id="leftImage" src="http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2014/09/Grumpy_Cat_Endorsement-017d7-ULFU.jpg"
   style="height: 33.70vw; max-width: 120.15vh;"/>
</div>
<div id="rightContainer" class="halfContainer">
 <img id="rightImage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg"
   style="height: 49.41vw; max-width: 81.95vh;"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Been a long time since I've seen the <center> tag...

Comment: Yeah well... it works. I use `<br/>`s too! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can set `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` on the image tags instead of hardcoding the height and max-widths on each image.

Then you can set `top: 40px;` on the `.halfContainer` divs to make the container start 40 pixels down.

Finally, set the `max-height` of the images to `calc(100vh - 40px);` so that they will always be the height between the header and the bottom of the page. `top: 0;` and `bottom: 0;` will then then make sure the images are lined up properly with the top and bottom of the container.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* Fix CSS. */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
html {
  background-color: #f4f4f6;
}
.halfContainer {
  width: 50vw;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
#leftContainer {
  left: 0;
}
#rightContainer {
  right: 0;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#leftImage {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 5%;
  /* Padding */
}
#rightImage {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5%;
}
#instructions {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1 id="instructions">Choose an image.</h1>
</center>
<div id="leftContainer" class="halfContainer">
  <img id="leftImage" src="http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2014/09/Grumpy_Cat_Endorsement-017d7-ULFU.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="rightContainer" class="halfContainer">
  <img id="rightImage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it still uses images (instead of divs with background-image, which is less ideal in my case), and because the images stay adjacent when the window is large. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I refactored your code to come up with this solution. This makes use of the `background-image` and `background-size` properties to size the images. I also moved away from `vh` and `vw` for sizing of other elements but you can change that back in `.wrapper`. The benefit is that it is a pure CSS solution; no JS. With a little tinkering it should fit your needs. Let me know if there are any concerns.

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing:border-box; }
body { margin:20px; height:calc(100% - 40px); width:calc(100% - 40px); }
html { height:100%; width:100%; }

.wrapper { position:relative; height:100%; width:100%; background-color: #f4f4f6; }
.title { text-align:center; height:2.4em; overflow:hidden; }

.left, .right { padding:15px; height:calc( 100% - 2.4em); width:50%; position:absolute; }
.left .imgCanvas, .right .imgCanvas { width:100%; height:100%; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain;  }

.left { right:50%; }
.left .imgCanvas { float:right; background-position:right;}
.right { left:50%;  }
.right .imgCanvas { float:left; background-position:left; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Choose an image</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <div class="imgCanvas" style="background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/g/500/3000')"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="imgCanvas" style="background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/g/3000/500')"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works well, thanks! Think I'm going to go with mikelt21's solution though as it still uses `<img>`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can give yourself more control over how your photos resize, and make your HTML and CSS a lot simpler if you use `background-image` for this (and it works in IE9) – here is how:

## Step 1 - Break this into smaller problems

Right now you are trying to position two different images, while taking their surroundings into account. Lets break that into two simpler problems by putting your images inside a `<div>` that I will call `#displayArea`. This way we can solve the placement of the `#displayArea` separately from solving the placement of the images.

So now we are trying to solve to easier problems:

1. Make our `#displayArea` - it should take up as much of the screen as possible without covering up the header at the top
2. Inside `#displayArea` place two images that are shown side-by-side, and fill the page while maintaining their aspect ratio and keeping the images next to each other

## Step 2 - make our `#displayArea`

We want `#displayArea` to take up as much space as possible. Lets start with width. In your css you set your `.halfContainer` to have widths of `50vw`, but you also set your `body` to have `20px` of margin - that means if we made our `#displayArea` `100vw` wide, the whole page would end up being `100vw + 40px` wide because of the left and right margins.

To allow you to change your page margins in the future without having to update your other css, I suggest you make your `#displayArea` fill all of the available space by setting its width to `100%`.

Next we need to set the `#displayArea` height. There are many ways to do this, but they all fall into two categories - ones that allow your header to have a dynamic height, and ones where it has a fixed height. I will assume that a fixed height for the header is ok, but do know that you will need a different solution if you want your header to have a dynamic height (such as allowing the text in it to wrap).

If we assume a fixed height, lets say of `40px`, then using CSS `calc()` we can set the height of `#displayArea` to be the height of the view port minus the header area and minus the body margin. It will look like this:

```
height: calc(100vh - 40px - 40px) /* 40px header, 40px for 2x20px top/bottom margin */
```

## Step 3 - Make the two images

Because we've already done some hard work setting up `#displayArea`, this step is pretty straight forward. While we can certainly make this work with the HTML you provided, I want to recommend you consider using `background-image` for this project. The amount of control css gives you on exactly how background images appear can save you a lot of time and trouble - for instance, when these images get small due to the browser window shrinking, do you want them to be vertically centered, or always as high up as possible? Easy to do with css background-image.

In my code below I use a class `.half` so the image divs can share styles. I then use their unique ids to set the specific image I want each of them to have.

Here is the finished CSS and HTML (note how simple the HTML is now).

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 /* Fix CSS. */
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body
{
 margin: 20px;
}

html
{
 background-color: #f4f4f6;
}

#instructions {
  height: 40px;
}

#displayArea {
  height: calc(100vh - 40px - 40px); /* 40px header, 40px for 2x20px top/bottom margin */
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.half {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
}

#leftImg {
  background-image: url(http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2014/09/Grumpy_Cat_Endorsement-017d7-ULFU.jpg);
  background-position: right top;
}

#rightImg {
  background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg);
  background-position: left top;
}
```

```html
<center><h1 id="instructions">Choose an image.</h1></center>
<div id="displayArea">
  <div id="leftImg" class="half"></div>
  <div id="rightImg" class="half"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost, but the images are centered in each half of the page which isn't what I wanted. Thanks anyway thought!

Comment: @Timmmm - I changed the CSS to show how you can have the images positioned to be right next to one another - there is a lot of flexibility with the background-position: CSS :-)

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already selected an answer, but I wanted to give you this option anyways.

Because you are using `vh` and `vw` measurements but not defining a header height, what you're asking to do is currently impossible without utilizing JavaScript to dynamically detect the size of the header to resize the columns. At that point, you might as well just use JavaScript to handle it and forget the viewport units.

Having said that, here is a JavaScript solution that will render the content, I believe, exactly how you want it rendered:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    window.left = document.getElementById("leftImage"),
   window.right = document.getElementById("rightImage"),
    window.head = document.getElementById("instructions"),
   window.leftW = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(left, null).getPropertyValue('width')),
  window.rightW = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(right, null).getPropertyValue('width')),
   window.leftH = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(left, null).getPropertyValue('height')),
  window.rightH = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(right, null).getPropertyValue('height'));

console.log(leftW);
    resize(leftW, rightW, leftH, rightH);
}

window.onresize = function() {
    resize(leftW, rightW, leftH, rightH);
}

function resize(leftW, rightW, leftH, rightH) {
    var winW = window.innerWidth,
      hcPadW = (winW * .025 * 2),
        winH = window.innerHeight,
      hcPadH = (winH * .025 * 2),
        colW = (winW / 2),
        colH = (winH - parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(head, null).getPropertyValue('height'))),
        colR = ((colW - hcPadW) / (colH - hcPadH)),
       leftR = (leftW / leftH),
      rightR = (rightW / rightH);
    
    if(colR < leftR) {
        left.style.width = (colW - hcPadW) + 'px';
        left.style.height = (((colW - hcPadW) * leftH) / leftW) + 'px';
    } else {
        left.style.height = (colH - hcPadH) + 'px';
        left.style.width = (((colH - hcPadH) * leftW) / leftH) + 'px';
    }
    
    if(colR < rightR) {
        right.style.width = (colW - hcPadW) + 'px';
        right.style.height = (((colW - hcPadW) * rightH) / rightW) + 'px';
    } else {
        right.style.height = (colH - hcPadH) + 'px';
        right.style.width = (((colH - hcPadH) * rightW) / rightH) + 'px';
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100vh;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #dedede;
    display: table;
}

#instructions, .hidden {
    display: table-row;
}

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#instructions {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #9a9a9a;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#cols {
    display: table-row;
}

.halfContainer {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2.5vh 2.5vw;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#leftContainer {
    background-color: #797979;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="hidden"><h1>Choose an image.</h1></div>
    <div id="instructions"><h1>Choose an image.</h1></div>
    <div id="cols">
        <div id="leftContainer" class="halfContainer"><img id="leftImage" src="http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2014/09/Grumpy_Cat_Endorsement-017d7-ULFU.jpg" class="image" /></div><div id="rightContainer" class="halfContainer"><img id="rightImage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg" class="image" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rLuf9zso/

Here's a bit more simplified of a route, minimizing the JavaScript to an absolute minimum:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var mH = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
    for(var i = 0; i < mH.length; i++) {
        mH[i].style['maxHeight'] = 'calc(94vh - ' + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('instructions'), null).getPropertyValue('height')) + 'px)';
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100vh;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    display: table;
}

#instructions, .hidden {
    display: table-row;
}

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#instructions {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#cols {
    display: table-row;
}

.halfContainer {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2.5vh 2.5vw;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#leftContainer {
    text-align: right;
}

.image {
    min-height: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    max-width: 40vw;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="hidden"><h1>Choose an image.</h1></div>
    <div id="instructions"><h1>Choose an image.</h1></div>
    <div id="cols">
        <div id="leftContainer" class="halfContainer"><img id="leftImage" src="http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2014/09/Grumpy_Cat_Endorsement-017d7-ULFU.jpg" class="image" /></div><div id="rightContainer" class="halfContainer"><img id="rightImage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg" class="image" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/18ynkzd0/

The primary difference between the two is going to be compatibility.  The first one, with the more extensive JavaScript, will be compatible in most major browsers going back several versions, whereas the second one follows your original scheme of ignoring browsers like IE 8/9, and Android 4.1/.3.

Something else to remember about these options is that the height of the header may be retrieved from `div#instructions`, but the positioning on the images isn't affected by it.  Since the header was positioned, it's height won't affect the rendering on the image positions.  To compensate, I added `div#hidden` with identical values/CSS and set its visibility to hidden.  This will add the height needed inline without displaying it.  If you change the displayed header, make sure you update the hidden `div` to match.

I hope this helps. ^^

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is definitely useful.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, even if it turns to have just provided some knowledge. ^^

Answer (score 0):

This might be a hack, but you could place a `<div style="height:50px"></div>` below your header.

You'll have to replace the height with the height of the header.

Comment: I think he posted a HTML Tag which got removed by the richtext editor

Answer (score 0):

Ok, slightly different answer now. I added the following to your code:

```
@media (max-height: 500px) {
    .halfContainer {
        top: 100px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
}
```

This will push down the images as soon as the screen-height gets below 200px. Overflow on auto wil disallow scrolling. You'll probably see less of the images.

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 /* Fix CSS. */
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body
{
 margin: 20px;
}

html
{
 background-color: #f4f4f6;
}

.halfContainer
{
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

@media (max-height: 500px) {
    .halfContainer {
        top: 100px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
}

#leftContainer
{
    left: 0;
}

#rightContainer
{
    right: 0;
}

/* AR is height/width. */

#leftImage
{
    /* Set to half width, minus padding. 50-padding = 45 */
    width: 45vw; 
 /* Multiply by aspect ratio. 45 * AR = ... */
    /*height: 35vw;*/
    /* Clip by height if necessary, minus padding. 100-padding*2 = 90 */
    max-height: 90vh;
 /* Divide by aspect ratio. 90 / AR = ... */
    /*max-width: 140vh; */
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 5%; /* Padding */
}


#rightImage
{
    /* Set to half width, minus padding. 50-padding = 45 */
    width: 45vw; 
 /* Multiply by aspect ratio. 45 * AR = ... */
    /*height: 35vw;*/
    /* Clip by height if necessary, minus padding. 100-padding*2 = 90 */
    max-height: 90vh;
 /* Divide by aspect ratio. 90 / AR = ... */
    /*max-width: 140vh;*/
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 5%;
}

#instructions
{
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1 id="instructions">Choose an image.</h1></center>

<div id="leftContainer" class="halfContainer">
 <img id="leftImage" src="http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2014/09/Grumpy_Cat_Endorsement-017d7-ULFU.jpg"
   style="height: 33.70vw; max-width: 120.15vh;"/>
</div>
<div id="rightContainer" class="halfContainer">
 <img id="rightImage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg"
   style="height: 49.41vw; max-width: 81.95vh;"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Almost! But the images go off the bottom of the page now.

Comment: Edited my answer with an `@media` query. Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't work still. Thanks anyway though! Looks like I'll have to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.halfContainer
{
   float:left;
   margin: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 150px;
}

.halfContainer img
{
    
    
   max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title> test </title>
  <meta charset="">
 
  </head>
 <body>

<center><h1 id="instructions">Choose an image.</h1></center>

<div class="halfContainer">
 <img src="http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2014/09/Grumpy_Cat_Endorsement-017d7-ULFU.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="halfContainer">
 <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg"/>
</div>


 </body>
</html>
```