# Is there any way to prevent images from stretching it's parent (flexbox)?

Tags: css, flexbox

This fiddle represents my problem:
    http://jsfiddle.net/LmYay/115

I want my page to be exactly 100% (of current screen resolution) wide and tall.
What is happening right now is that image is stretching content box, and I wan't the image to be scaled down to fit the content box (so the page is always 100% tall). I can think of JS sollution that would check for parent's height and then set the img's max-height to parent's height. Oh and setting max-height property to inherit did not work neither.

```css
*, *:before, *:after{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    background: #222;
    color: #cccccc;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.flexbox-parent{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    justify-content: flex-start; 
    align-items: stretch; 
    align-content: stretch; 
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.flexbox-item{
    padding: 8px;
}

.flexbox-item.header{
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .1);
}

.flexbox-item.footer{
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .1);
}

.flexbox-item.content{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .1);
}

.fill-area{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;    
    justify-content: flex-start; 
    align-items: center; 
    align-content: stretch; 
    flex: 1
}
.fill-area-content{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-parent">
<div class="flexbox-item header">
    Header
</div>

<div class="flexbox-item fill-area content">
    <div class="fill-area-content flexbox-item-grow">

        <div class="my-images">
            <div><img  class="img-responsive-custom" src="http://placehold.it/297x1006.gif" alt=""/> </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="flexbox-item footer">
    Footer
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're encountering the same problem as [Timmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265521/timmmm) did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27820643/3869056).  As I explained in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27948361/3869056), there is an actual method of doing this without JavaScript.  The problem you're encountering is the image needs to be sized to the remaining height of the screen, subtracting the height of the `.header` and `.footer` from the screen size.

The simplest solution to to specify `height`s for the `.header` and `.footer` and `max-height`s for everything in-between.

```css
*,:before,:after {
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box
}

.k img {
    height:100%
}

html,body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

body {
    background:#222;
    color:#ccc;
    font-size:22px;
/* Helvetica/Arial-based sans serif stack */
    font-family:Frutiger,"Frutiger Linotype",Univers,Calibri,"Gill Sans","Gill Sans MT","Myriad Pro",Myriad,"DejaVu Sans Condensed","Liberation Sans","Nimbus Sans L",Tahoma,Geneva,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

.flexbox-parent {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:flex-start;
/* align items in Main Axis */
    align-items:stretch;
/* align items in Cross Axis */
    align-content:stretch;
/* Extra space in Cross Axis */
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.1)
}

.flexbox-item {
    padding:8px
}

.flexbox-item-grow {
    flex:1
/* same as flex: 1 1 auto; */
}

.flexbox-item.header {
    background:rgba(255,0,0,.1)
}

.flexbox-item.footer {
    background:rgba(0,255,0,.1)
}

.flexbox-item.content {
    background:rgba(0,0,255,.1)
}

.fill-area {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:flex-start;
/* align items in Main Axis */
    align-items:stretch;
/* align items in Cross Axis */
    align-content:stretch
/* Extra space in Cross Axis */
}

.fill-area-content {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border:1px solid #000
/* Needed for when the area gets squished too far and there is content that can't be displayed */
}

.header,.footer {
    height:43px
}

.content {
    max-height:calc(100vh - 86px)
}

.k img {
    height:calc(100vh - 102px)
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-parent">
    <div class="flexbox-item header">
        Header
    </div>

    <div class="flexbox-item fill-area content flexbox-item-grow">
        <div class="fill-area-content flexbox-item-grow">
            <div class="k">
                <div><img alt="" class="img-responsive-custom" src="http://placehold.it/297x1006.gif"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flexbox-item footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vL83trtr/

The only edit I made (other than cleaning up the format a little, was adding to the CSS:

```css
.header,.footer {
    height:43px
}

.content {
    max-height:calc(100vh - 86px)
}

.k img {
    height:calc(100vh - 102px)
}
```

My thoughts are that since you're using flexbox, you're not overly concerned with backwards compatibility, for `vh` and `calc()` are ideal for pulling this off when you can give everything above and below what you need sized a fixed `height`.

Please, note that `height` includes `padding`, so it has to compensate for the padding applied by other classes.  Work in this manner is a sure thing to work in newer browsers once you have the values set to exactly what you need.

If you do need compatibility with older browsers, I recommend the JavaScript I posted for Timmmm.

I hope this helps. ^^